# How could Naruto twist his ankle?

Tags: naruto

Well, when Naruto was fighting Sasuke at the Valley of the End, Sasuke popped a hole in his shoulder, to prevent him from using the Rasengan.

Naruto, in response, activated his Nine-tails chakra (to less than one tail), and the hole healed so fast it was actually visibly closed.

---

A few years into the future, Naruto has (almost) *complete control* over the Nine-tails' chakra! And yet, when he attacked Kisame, he twisted his ankle, and that didn't heal until much later.

What the hell? That chakra had enough life force to sprout trees from Yamato's logs! Why couldn't it heal a simple twisted ankle? Can we dismiss it as a case of "Allow Gai to fight Kisame and provide Naruto an excuse to stay out of it"?

Comment: The more time passes and Naruto grows, so does his stupidity.

Comment: Hashirama Senju answering Madara Uchiha's question.hmm ok

Answer (score 8, accepted):

During his battle with Sasuke in the Valley of the End Naruto was not in control of the nine tails. The Nine Tails was acting on his own accord, triggered by the emotions of Naruto.

But during the battle with Kisame, Naruto was in control of the Nine Tails. Infact he had just gained control of it. So I would guess that, since he only recently gained control of the nine tails, he was not in sync with the Nine Tail's power, which is displayed by Naruto misjudging his speed and power thereby spraining/fracturing his ankle.

One can have all the raw power in him, but unless the body is in sync with the power, you are no good. Also, about the fallen Zetsu's or wood element's sprouting leaves, this is not done by Naruto, but rather it is done by Naruto's/Kurama's chakra resonating in the wood element. (Zetsu has Hashirama's cells).

Well this is my two cents.

Comment: HE was also in a special Chakra cloak different than the normal Biju chakra cloak, which has never shown to rapidly heal his injuries (not that he ever got any with it on), plus its just a twisted ankle, nothing to worry over, and possibly no actual damage to the muscles to heal in the first place. Google wont even acknowledge their existence for me to find out why i can twist my ankle and be unable to stand, but 2 minutes later be walking normally.

Answer (score 3):

Well, there are plot holes which Kishimoto makes up most of the time. Some things can not be reasoned without the wildest guesses.

For example, when Orochimaru attacked Konoha by using Edo Tensei on the First and Second, neither they used the Flying Thunder God of the Second, nor he used the Thousand Hands Jutsu of First with which he could have clearly overpowered the Third.

Well, we can just say, it was a twisted ankle, so healing doesn't work with twisted ankles like it does with wounds, for which healing can be done with sprouting new cells.

Comment: I think the part with Orochimaru not utilizing the previous Hokages was reasoned as Orochimaru hadn't perfected Edo Tensei, and couldn't revive them at their full strength (which he could, when he revived them the second time).

Comment: @MadaraUchiha, your comment can be an answer.

Comment: @NaraShikamaru but that was not his question!